# Angular and javascript scope for variable access

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

In the view I'm declaring the controller like so:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">
     {{myCtrl.selectedMonth}}
</div>
```

I want to be able to access a month in the view, but I don't want the date object to be accessible from the view. Would this do it? Is testabc accessible from the view? Is this a good way to have privately scoped variables on the controller?

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    function myController() {

        var testabc = 'can you see this';
        var dateRef = new Date();
        var vm = this;

        angular.extend(vm, {
                selectedMonth: undefined
        });

        init();

        function init(){

            vm.selectedMonth = dateRef.getMonth();
        }


    }

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

First dont trigger init in controller as it sometimes creates issues. you can use angular ng-init directive.

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    function myController() {

        var testabc = 'can you see this';
        var dateRef = new Date();
        var vm = this;

        angular.extend(vm, {
                selectedMonth: undefined,
                init:init
        });



        function init(){

            vm.selectedMonth = dateRef.getMonth();
        }


    }

}());
```

and your view will be

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController as myCtrl" ng-init="myCtrl.init()">
     {{myCtrl.selectedMonth}}
</div>
```

P.S yes your selectedMonth is visible in view.

Comment: Is testabc accessible from the view? Is declaring vars at the top of the controller like this a good way to have privately scoped variables?

Comment: What kinds of issues does triggering init in the controller cause?

Answer (score 0):

Anything you bind to the scope will be accessible in the view. Scope is the glue between your controller and your HTML view. If you need only the month to be accessible just bind it to vm.

```
vm.selectedMonth= dateRef.getMonth();
```

This line would be just enough.

Comment: The question is more, is declaring vars at the top of the controller a good practice for having privately scoped variables?

Comment: I think you are a bit confused between JavaScript and Java. These controllers are not shared across users. it's all instantiated on the client side. In Java usually when we have Singleton class we avoid having variables declared at the top of the class otherwise it will be shared across all the threads. If you need a variable that there is no other controller can compromise unintentionally then bind to the scope it will get created with the scope and destroyed with the scope.